# Does FreeBSD support the AR9380 chipset?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, freebsd

I'm building a file server (home use) and would like to put in a wireless card based on the Atheros AR9380 chipset. However I can't find whether this one is supported or not. I know there is the ahk9k driver for Linux which supposedly supports it but is it supported under FreeBSD 9.0 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled across [this wiki page](http://wiki.freebsd.org/dev/ath_hal%284%29/HardwareSupport). So the answer is: No, not yet.

Comment: my AR5008 is mentioned their neither, "works" nevertheless. i would say: buy one and try.

Comment: @akira Well, AR93xx is listed under "Chipsets I might work on in the future" with "requires porting from the ahk9k driver". So I'll get a 300Mbit card with a AR9287 chipset for now.

Comment: still, buy a AR9380 and keep me posted :)

Comment: I have one. Not supported yet in 9-STABLE. Saw some commits mentioning 9300 in cvs though. Maybe soon?

Answer (score 0):

It's `168c:0030`.

Supported since FreeBSD 10.0: https://github.com/bsdhw/Drivers/blob/master/freebsd/freebsd-10.0.list

See https://bsd-hardware.info/?id=pci:168c-0030-168c-3112